# Tengo un problema con los CORS en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

lo que sucede es que cuando intento pedir los datos a una api en este caso es la de Riot Games tengo el problema de que cuando la solicito me muestra que hubo un error de cors es este específicamente :

> **has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.**

estoy programando con react y la cree utilizando el comando

```
create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El  control same-origin policy esta creado para combatir uno de los ciber ataques mas comunes: **cross-site request forgery**. Este ataque comienza, cuando un website fraudulento trata de aprovechar las cookies almacenadas en el navegador para enviar una solicitud fraudulenta. Partiendo de este analisis inicial vamos a las posibles soluciones:

**Solucion 1**: Instalar el Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin (lo he hecho con Chrome y Firefox)

La manera mas sencilla de arreglar este problema es instalando el moesif CORS extension . Una cuando este instalado cliquea tu navegador y asegurate que la extension esta activa. Asegurate que la etiqueta esta en off: Esta solucion es solo para desarrollo no es valida para el ambiente de producion.

**Solucion 2**: Enviar tu soliciud a un proxy

Usted necesita hace una solicitud a `https://cerveza-api-strict-cors.barcelona.com/alemana/todas`

En cambio usted envia la solicitud a: 
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cerveza-api-strict-s.barcelona.com/alemana/todas

Y esto puede resolver el asunto en desarrollo y producion.

Este error sucede basicamente porque la URL desde donde estas llamando el API no esta registrada como valida en la configuracion de CORS en el API por lo tanto si puede modificar el API y agregar esta URL el problema estaria resuelto.

Espero sirva la explicacion, como punto de partida para encontrar la solucion definitiva.
Gracias